# What is the quality of these 10 example sentences obtained through sentence mining?

Tags: sentence

A software package on Github called [`chinese-sentence-miner`](https://github.com/Destaq/chinese-sentence-miner) seemed like it would be useful, until I looked at its example sentences:

> 1. **我看**你不应该。 (I don't think you ought to.)
> 2. 我喜欢约翰，他是我非常要好的朋友。 (I like John, a very good friend of mine.)
> 3. 我喜欢夏天吃**莴苣**，我的兔子也喜欢。 (I like to eat lettuce in summer, and so does my rabbit.)
> 4. 请帮我喂我的猫好吗？ (Will you feed my cat for me?)
> 5. 我喜欢唱歌，**更不用说**听音乐了。 (I enjoy singing, much more than listening to music.)
> 6. 我没有注意到他已经走了。 (I failed to note that he had left.)
> 7. 妈妈准备了好吃的东西给我。 (Mother has something delicious in store for me.)
> 8. 我觉得这是我的义务。 (I feel it is my duty.)
> 9. 我有一辆红色的自行车。 (I have a red bike.)
> 10. 我可以用信用卡付款吗？ (May I pay by credit card.)
>
> <sub>[chinese-sentence-miner](https://github.com/Destaq/chinese-sentence-miner) ([source of these examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o85rg.png))</sub>

I think 2, 4, and 6-10 are fine.  My impression is that 1 is wrong.  In 3, 莴苣 seems like a obscure choice of word for "lettuce" which I would normally call 生菜.  I'm not sure what 更不用说 means in 5, but it seems backwards: they like music more than singing.  Maybe others can offer more insight.

**Question**: What is the quality of these 10 example sentences obtained through sentence mining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Q: 我應該去嗎? A: 我看你不应该。

(3) 莴苣 means (from dictionary) lettuce, cos lettuce, romaine, and asparagus lettuce. Note that 生菜 refers to the uncooked fresh vegetables that are not limited to lettuce.

(10) 我喜欢唱歌，更不用说听音乐了。My translation - I like singing, it goes without saying I like to listen to the music.

I wouldn't comment on the quality of these sentences, but I don't quite support the way that many teaching material only provide a phrase (片語), though grammatically correct, which does not provide a complete picture to promote understanding.

Comment: Interestingly,  in Cantonese, 生菜 refers to lettuce exclusively. All vegetables are presumed uncooked in the market and cooked in dishes except for lettuce. We have 生嘅生菜 (uncooked lettuce)  and 熟嘅生菜 (cooked lettuce)

Comment: @TangHo I've no comment on "Cantonese" terms.